# mathematical induction proof of a square vs factorial

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So lets say I have $$ n^{2} \le n! $$

For what positive integers is this not true? $n=2$ and $ 3$

Base case? $$n=4 \implies  16 \le 24 $$

What is the inductive hypothesis and how do I show the inductive proof? Thanks

Comment: Assume that for some $k>4$, $k^2\le k!$.  Then, show this is true for $(k+1)^2\le (k+1)!$

Comment: If we restrain $n$ to be as $n\geq 4,\;n\in\mathbb{N}$, and if for $n_0=4$ you just showed that it holds, then if we assume that the inequality holds for some natural $k>4$, then it is sufficient to prove that for some natural $k+1$ the above expression also holds. The main point is that whenever we fix $k$, *provided it's greater than* $4$, and knowing that the inequality holds, therefore we can say that it's surely true for all $k\geq 4$.

Answer (score 4):

If $n^2<n!$ and $n\ge4$ then
$$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1<n!+2n+1<n!+3n<n!+n!n=n!(n+1)=(n+1)!$$

Another way:
$$(n+1)^2=n^2\left(1+\frac1n\right)^2<n!\cdot 4<n!(n+1)=(n+1)!$$

Comment: I like that $3<n!$ for large $n$ is a useful fact somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For, $ x_0 = 4 $, $ n^2 \le n! $ is true.

Now, given, $n^2 \le n!$,

$(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1$,

and, $ n^2 \le n! \implies n^2(n+1)^2 \le (n+1)^2n!$

$\implies (n+1)^2 \le (\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n}) * (n+1)!$

$n > 4 => \frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{16} $ and $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{4} $, So,

$ (\frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n}) \lt \frac5{16} < 1$

As, $ (n+1)^2 \le \frac5{16} * (n+1)! \implies (n+1)^2 \le (n+1)!$

Comment: very detailed thanks